# How to add an attribute to Nokogiri XML builder?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |x|
  x.root do
    x.book do
      x.attribute('isbn', 12345) # Doesn't work!
      x.text("Don Quixot")
    end
  end
end.doc
```

I know that I can do `x.book(isbn: 12345)`, but this is not what I want. I want to add an attribute within the `do/end` block. Is it at all possible?

The XML expected:

```
<root>
  <book isbn="12345">Don Quixot</book>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you manually whip up some XML to give us a visual of what you are trying to create?

Comment: @ddubs just updated the answer, see above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the attributes to the node like this

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |x|
  x.root do
    x.book(isbn: 1235) do
      x.text('Don Quixot')
    end
  end
end.doc
```

Or, after re-rereading your question perhaps you wanted to add it to the parent further in the do block. In that case, this works:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |x|
  x.root do
    x.book do
      x.parent.set_attribute('isbn', 12345)
      x.text('Don Quixot')
    end
  end
end.doc
```

Generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <book isbn="1235">Don Quixot</book>
</root>
```